# Is there an attitude to avoid piping downloaded data sent to stdout?

Tags: pipe, download, corruption

Please consider the following command:

```
wget FILE -O - | tar -xzv -C DESTINATION
```

I understood from programmer [who reviewed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/233104/125391) a Bash code I created that it is better to separate `tar` from `wget` to prevent cases of extracting a file that was downloaded in an erroneous way, based on a comment:

> Downloading the files should be a separate step from upgrading since
>   the internet might fail just at the moment you want to upgrade. If you
>   download the files first, you can just skip that step later. It also
>   saves bandwidth. For example, in pkgsrc...

I understood from [man bash on set builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html), that using `set -euo` would allow using `wget` safely because due to `-e` option; if there is no success (non-zero exit code) the pipeline would not transfer the data into `tar`.

Is there an attitude to avoid piping downloaded data sent to stdout?

Comment: From the page you linked: "The shell does not exit if the command that fails is [...] any command in a pipeline but the last". At the least, if I was using the script for anything in production, I'd want some error handling for download failures (retry, logging, exit code, fallback etc.)

Comment: My bad not to read the entire `-e` chapter; that is surprising because I got another comment like "I would use `-e` if something gets wrong" ; none of the similar comments reminded any of these exceptions; I am surprised there is no exception for "the last which is also the only one". I guess my question became not valid per your comment, do you agree?...

Comment: If you require any additional clarification, you can edit your question to reflect it, but otherwise I agree.

Answer (score 2):

`-e` won't help here:  "The shell does not exit if the command that fails is ... any command in a pipeline but the last".

As to whether it is a good idea. It depends, what would the consequences be?

Comment: Hello dear ctrl-alt-delor ; please read the short correspondence between me and  gnubeard and consider to delete your answer because it seems my entire question is non valid and misleading; writing this to you is my responsibility.